# Java application( hosted on Tomcat)session timeout while trying to access through NLB

Tags: java, tomcat, web, tomcat5.5, nlb

There is a NLB ip which is mapped to five different servers. Each server has the same java application deployed on Tomcat5.5. Now, while trying to access the java application through NLB the application is opening alright but after a few clicks somehow the session is getting expired. What could be the issue and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Search for "session stickiness" - essentially you need to configure the load balancer so that requests that are part of the same session are directed to the same back-end server.

Comment: could you please divulge some more details.. What are the configurations required?

Comment: I've used various load balancers but not this particular one so while I know _what_ you need to do in principle you'll have to look up the _how_ for yourself.  Seriously, google "session stickiness nlb" and you'll probably find the documentation you need.

Comment: I have been able to implement this successfully after reading the documentation provided by Tomcat. Thanks for your help!